# Javascript apply not working correctly

Tags: javascript

Please can you tell me why my .apply() is not working the way I want. What am I doing wrong?

I am expecting

Hi, Alice, I'm  Bob

Hi, Steve, I'm  Bob

Hi, Mark , I'm  Bob

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


        var friendlyGreet = function() {


            $.each(arguments, function(index, val) {

                  alert("Hi, " + val.name + ", I'm " + this.name);
            });



        };


        var Bob = {
            name: "Bob"
        };

        var Alice = {
            name: "Alice"
        };

        var Mark = {
            name: "Mark"
        };

        var Steve = {
            name: "Steve"
        };

        friendlyGreet.apply(Bob,[Alice,Steve,Mark]);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see what you are expecting : http://jsfiddle.net/MQh4M/

Comment: @TJ- I don't. I see `Hi, Alice, I'm Alice`, etc... Chrome 33.0.1750.146 m

Comment: My bad. I didn't see the output statements, very well. Check what @sabof has to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `apply` is working, but `this` inside `$.each` is referring to the element being looped on, and not the main object.

```
var friendlyGreet = function() {
  var self = this;
  $.each(arguments, function(index, val) {
    alert("Hi, " + val.name + ", I'm " + self.name);
  });
};
```